# Does the appcenter support connecting to Apple store?

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I am trying to publish my app to Apple Store, but I do not see the Apple store option in creating a connection to store panel.
Is Apple store supported in Appcenter?

Comment: I have seen the docs but like you I cannot see it :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, App Center does provide an option to make a connection to to App Store Connect so that your iOS applications can be submitted to the App Store or to TestFlight.

Here is the link to the App Center documentation that walks through how to set up the connection to App Store Connect: [Publish to App Store Connect - Visual Studio App Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/stores/apple)